# How to restrict internet access in a VPC with a nat gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have setup a VPC with two subnets `public` and `private`. There are many lambdas in the VPC and a few of them needs internet access. So I added NAT gateway on the VPC. However, it makes every lambda to be able to get internet access. How can I control which lambdas can have internet access in the VPC with a NAT gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NAT gateways **do not have security groups** (SGs) nor access policies. Thus, you can't control access to the internet using NAT. But there are some surrogate measures you can consider:

- Create a **private subnet without a route** to the NAT and place your lambda functions there. Without the route to NAT, nothing from this subnet will be able to communicate with the internet.
- Create a special **SG with custom outgoing rule**, e.g. allow only outgoing traffic to CIDR of your VPC, or to SGs which they are only allowed to communicate with.
- Create **dedicate private VPC** only for lambda functions, and peer it with your primary VPC. VPC peering is not-transitive, which means that your functions won't be able to use NAT from the primary VPC.

Comment: If I use the first option, then I will have to create three subnets in the VPC. One private without a route to the NAT. One private with a route to the NAT and one public. Is it correct?

Comment: @Yes, that's right. And you will place lambda functions in the private subnet without nat.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the lambdas need access to certain resources in the subnet in which they are deployed.

If that's the case, then I suggest you create a security group with the desired settings and assign that security group to all lambdas which you want to restrict access for.

If that's not the case, you can simply remove the VPC association at the lambda level.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is my use case. That means I can't use NAT gateway to control who can have internet access or not?

Comment: I think you are making some confusion. All a NAT does is allow instances in a private subnet to talk to the internet. You are dealing with lambdas, not instances.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple answer:** Any AWS Lambda function connected to a public subnet will *not* have access to the Internet.

This is because the route table for the public subnet does not send traffic through the NAT Gateway, and the Lambda function itself is unable to use the Internet Gateway to access the Internet.

Comment: I do need some of my lambdas to have access to internet. so I have an internet gateway in the VPC.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Any Lambda functions that need Internet access should be connected to a private subnet. Any that should _not_ have Internet access should be connected to a public subnet.